# C++: Read individual lines from text file, sort words alphabetically

Tags: c++, file, sorting, text, vector

I've created a text file with 3 lines filled with random words. I want to :

- Read each line in the file individually.
- Sort the words in each line alphabetically
- Output the sorted line to console.

This is what I've come up with so far [runnable]: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6211515

It reads the lines and puts them inside a vector, sorts that vector and then prints the resulting vector to console. But I'm just sorting the lines, I'm not sorting the actual words. I'm inputting the entire line as a string, which is causing my problems. I'm very new to C++ programming and I'm not sure what I should do to be able to sort the actual words, not the lines.

This is not homework, it's just a problem that was suggested to me that I solve in preparation for an upcoming exam. It is of paramount importance that the solution be as simple as possible as this exam will be done with pen and paper.

Answer (score 2):

At least if I understand what you want correctly, I'd do something like this:

1. Read a line into a string with `std::getline`.
2. Initialize a `std::stringstream` from the string
3. Read words from the stringstream into a vector
4. Sort the vector
5. Write the sorted words to the output.
6. Repeat until done.

Comment: Thank you, this sound like the solution I'm looking for. I'm not sure how I would implement this though! I've never used stringstream before. I've only known about vectors and sorting for the last two days!

Comment: @Haugum: a stringstream works like other streams, so you could (for example) use something like: `while (your_stream >> word) words.push_back(word);`

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a `lexicographical sorting` algorithm. Which means, sort word's just like in dictionaries, with alphabetical order.

Standard c++ supports that algorithm. Take alook here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/

In order to access the implementation just `#include <algorithm>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to write an algorithm that will do this, rather than use anything at all that's pre-written.

Once you have the strings in the vector, now you need to separate each one into words. So you would want to loop through each character in each string in the vector, find the spaces (or whatever delimiter your file is using), and then put everything before each space into another vector. And delete everything you find before each space from the string once you record it, so that it doesn't show up a second time. 
Now you have a vector of words. Then just sort that vector the same way you're currently sorting text_file.